# Validation for Filepicker is not working in Moodle

Tags: validation, moodle, filepicker

`Validation` in **Moodle** `filepicker` is not working. My form is **add_form.php**

```
require_once("{$CFG->libdir}/formslib.php");

class add_form extends moodleform {

    function definition() {
        global $DB;
        $mform =&$this->_form;
        // add question title.
        $mform->addElement('header','displayinfo', 'Add/Edit Question');
        $mform->addElement('editor', 'question', 'Question');
        $mform->addRule('question', null, 'required', null, 'client');
        $mform->setType('question', PARAM_RAW);
        $maxbytes = 0;
        $mform->addElement('filepicker', 'answerfile', get_string('file'), null,
                   array('maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => array('document','.txt', '.pdf')));
        $mform->addRule('answerfile', null, 'required', null, 'client');
        $mform->setType('answerfile', PARAM_RAW);


        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'blockid');
        $mform->setType('blockid', PARAM_RAW);
        $mform->addElement('hidden', 'courseid');
        $mform->setType('courseid', PARAM_RAW);
        $this->add_action_buttons(false, 'SAVE');

    }
}
```

Here the `required validation` for first field(`question`) is working. But the `validation` (required) for `answerfile` is not working. I am using two fields `one editor and one filepicker fields.`

When I submit the button with empty value(no files choosen) in `filepicker` the form get submitted.

```
Why the validation for file picker is not working here.
```

Please help me...

**Moodle ver: 2.9.1**

Answer (score 1):

Might be the client side validation isn't working. Try server side validation. If that works, then it might be something to do with javascript on the client side.

```
$mform->addRule('answerfile', null, 'required');
```

Answer (score 0):

File validation rule works only if we pass first parameter in moodleform custructor. 
Use `$mform = new add_form($pageurl);` insted of `$mform = new add_form();` where you have instantiate add_form object. 
$pageurl is url of page where form data submitted.

I checked your code and it works for both client and server side validation if parameter is used.